# POSIXct in R returns NA, whats the reason?

Tags: r, datetime

I have dataset with column time. it includes the date and the time together. However, I want to have only the **Hour and Minute** in a separate column and then to plot it with another column. However, i tried using:

```
today$Clock<- as.POSIXct(today$time, origin="%H:%M:%S")
today["Clock"] <- within(today$time, ISOdatetime(YY,MM,DD,hh,mm,0))
today$Clock<- strptime(x = as.character(today$time),
                                format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

and nothing is working..i either get NA or the same value of date.

Here is some of my dataset:

```
    id        fname       uname            time            COUNT...
1   111449  o1              Name1       2015-03-03 16:14:32 1
2   100833  o1              Name2       2014-11-28 23:19:15 1
3   100834  o1              Name2       2014-11-28 23:20:52 1
4   100835  o1              Name3       2014-11-28 23:21:04 1
5   100921  o1              Name3       2014-11-30 00:55:56 1
6   100922  o1              Name3       2014-11-30 00:56:06 1
7   105983  o1              Name4       2014-12-25 01:22:42 1
8   108761  o1              Name5       2015-02-01 00:56:55 1
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I might be wrong, but `origin` in `as.POSIXct` should be something like `"1960-01-01"`, not `"%H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: hello, yes, this was one of my tries.. i used format...etc. nothing is working with me

Comment: Also, in `strptime`, `format` should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

Comment: Try something like `library(data.table) ; IDateTime(as.POSIXct(today$time))`, the `itime` column can be manipulated easily afterwords

Comment: Please add to your post a `dput(head(today))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract the hour and the minute, there is no need to make the variable of class `POSIXct`. You just use `substr` to extract the relevant time parts out of the string variable

```
str <- c('2015-03-03 16:14:32',
        '2014-11-28 23:19:15',
        '2014-11-28 23:20:52',
        '2014-11-28 23:21:04',
        '2014-11-30 00:55:56',
        '2014-11-30 00:56:06',
        '2014-12-25 01:22:42',
        '2015-02-01 00:56:55')
as.integer(substr(str, 12,13))
as.integer(substr(str, 15,16))
```

Comment: but to plot it using ggplot2, they should be POSIXct

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are after.